# Remaining time calculation using NSDate working on simulator but not in Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios6

i am using below code to calculate remaining time that code working good on Simulator but it gives all zero value to day hours minutes and seconds on iPad device

```
`NSTimeInterval remainingSec = [databaseDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (!timer || remainingSec <= 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
        // getting time from database



NSLocale *indianEnglishLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFrmattr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFrmattr setLocale:indianEnglishLocale];
    [dateFrmattr setDateFormat:@"V"];
    [dateFrmattr setTimeZone:timeZone];
    dateFrmattr.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
    dateFrmattr.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
    NSDate *finalDate = [dateFrmattr dateFromString:@"11/01/2012 10:00:00 IST"];

   // NSDate *startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    self.databaseDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];;
    remainingSec = [finalDate timeIntervalSinceDate:databaseDate];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(showClock)  
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];
}
//NSInteger remainder = ((NSInteger)remainingSec)% 3600;
NSInteger days = remainingSec/86400;
NSInteger int1 = ((NSInteger)remainingSec) % 86400;
NSInteger hours = int1/3600;
NSInteger int2 = int1 % 3600;
NSInteger minutes = int2/60;
NSInteger seconds = int2 % 60;

clockLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %02d  :  %02d  :  %02d  :  %02d ", days,hours, minutes, seconds];
```

value of final date is zero on device but right on simulator.

My app is universal app the time calculation working fine on iPhone Device.
Any idea or help

Comment: Have you set some breakpoints and stepped through your code to examine what the values are at each point through the code and therefore determine where the values are going wrong?

Comment: yes nick i check the value of final date is right for simulator and nil for device

Comment: It is possible that iOS does not support the en_IN locale, or possibly not the Asia/Kolkata time zone name. Check if your NSLocale or NSTimeZone objects are nil.

Comment: @ChrisLundie NSLocale and NSTimeZone are not nil only finalDate is nil..the app is working fine on iPhone Device.

Comment: I can't guarantee this work, but try setting `formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];` rather than `en_IN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing '**zzz**' from NSDateFormatter and '**IST**' from date string it works on iPad.But still have a question that why the previous code works on iPhone and not in iPad? After removing time zone from NSDateFormatter and date string it works.